# How to deal with string format in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like following:

```
    pop    state  country       num_1      num_2
 0  1.8    Ohio   China          1           4
 1  1.9    Ohio   China          1           5
 2  3.9  Nevada   Britain        1           6
 3  2.9  Nevada   Germany        1           2
 4  2.0  Nevada   Japan          1           7
```

You can see in this data frame, df['country'] have 4 different values. I can use 00=China,01=Britain,10=Germany,11=Japan to mean its values. And df['num_1      '],df['num_2'] have 1, 5 different values. I can also mean it value as binary num.

So I want to condense this data frame to a small data frame as following:

```
     pop    state  value       
  0  1.8    Ohio   000000
  1  1.9    Ohio   000001        
  2  3.9  Nevada   010010
  3  2.9  Nevada   100011
  4  2.0  Nevada   110100
```

My problem is how can I write code to compress this data frame and uncompress  it.

Comment: If you are looking for ways to save memory, use [categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) Otherwise I don't see how this would improve anything.

Comment: what are you referring to as value1, value2, value3?

Comment: @ayhan hi, I just  used a example of value1,value2,value3... The fact is it may have 200+ different cols and each cols have only 3~5 different values. So I want to compress it by using a string.

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao Hi, I have edited the content. Thx~~~

Comment: `df[['state', 'num_1', 'num_2']].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).applymap(np.binary_repr)` this will give you the binary representation for each one. You can use the width parameter of np.binary_repr, `zfill` or similar string methods to pad zeros (It's not clear from your example how many zeros should be padded) and finally join. But this will be super inefficient. Again, I recommend looking at categoricals.

Comment: @ayhan hi,ayhan. you can see in df['country'], it has 4 different values. So I need 2 bit. And df['num_1'], it has 1 value. So I need 1 bit. And df['num_1'], I have 5 different values, then I need 3 bit. So I compress it to df['value'] with 7 bit. The first two bits represent df['country'], the third bit represent df['num_1']. The last three bits represent df['num_2']

Answer (score 1):

OK let's start with a random DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(list('ABC'), 10**7),
                   'B': 1,
                   'C': np.random.choice(list('xyztq'), 10**7)})

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A    object
B    int64
C    object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 228.9+ MB
```

What happens if you use categoricals:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A    category
B    category
C    category
dtypes: category(3)
memory usage: 28.6 MB
```

With binary representations:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].cat.codes.apply(lambda x: np.binary_repr(x, 2))
df['B'] = df['B'].cat.codes.apply(lambda x: np.binary_repr(x))
df['C'] = df['C'].cat.codes.apply(lambda x: np.binary_repr(x, 3))
df.head()
Out: 
    A  B    C
0  00  0  010
1  01  0  001
2  00  0  100
3  01  0  001
4  01  0  001
```

And the memory usage:

```
ser = df.apply(''.join, axis=1)
ser.to_frame().info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 76.3+ MB
```